# JQuery Submit button not working

Tags: jquery, forms, post, serialization

So I have a 3 page registration page. On the first page there are three options, if the user chooses the first option then the submit button is shown at the bottom of the 2nd page. If the user chooses option 2 or 3 then on the 2nd page the submit button will only appear after selecting a certain radio button. Here's the code for the 2nd page:

```
<form id="everything" method="post" action="Page3.php">
<input type="radio" id="Reg_num_r1" name="Reg_num_r" value="1"/> Register 1 <br/>
<input type="radio" id="Reg_num_r2" name="Reg_num_r" value="2"/> Registration 1+ <br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"  style="display:none;"/>
</form>
```

Here's the JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
if(type==1) {
        $("#submit").show();
    }

$("input[name= 'Reg_num_r']").change( function () {
        if($(this).val()==1) {
            $('#Reg_num2').hide();
        } else {
            $('#Reg_num2').show();
        }
        $("#submit").show();
    });
$("#everything").submit( function() {
        var data = $("#everything").serialize();
        alert(data);
        return true;
    });
}
```

If I selected the first option on the first page and click the submit button on the 2nd page, it works perfectly and I move onto the 3rd page. However if I pick option 2 or 3 then the submit button just doesn't work. I continuously click it and nothing happens. I think it's because it is hidden at the beginning since its option 2 or 3 but i don't know a workaround for this. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: What is type==1 is supposed to check?

Comment: Can you see in Firebug if there is somekind of JS error, always helps in debugging...

Comment: I don't think there should be a space between `name=` and `'Reg_num_r'`.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to reference a form with an id in `$("#everything").submit()` but that form only has a name. either give it an id or change your code to `$("form[name='everything']").submit()`

Comment: try to change your submit button to `<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"  style="display:none;"/>` and change your js to `$('input[name="submit"]).click(function(){
$("#everything").submit( function() {
        var data = $("#everything").serialize();
        alert(data);
        return true;
    });
});`

Answer (score 0):

The `$("#everything")` selector does not exist. Your form does not have this id. Try:

```
$("form[name=everything]").submit( function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#everything") is the ID in the selector.. But you do not have a form with ID  

<form name="everything" id="everything"
```

Make this change for it to work..

Comment: Place an alert in the submit event and check where you see the alert or not.. If you see the alert do you see the request in the browser